# Flutter Copy & Past Popup Got Overflowed from the viewport

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have used FormTextField widget to handle authentication page.
The issue is when I select the content of FormTextField, shown Popup got overflowed from the viewport. here is an image that describes the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my `Theme` config in the `main.dart` file.

the issue was applying `minWidth` to all `Button`s widget that makes the problem. When I remove the `minWidth` from the `buttonTheme` that defined in `ThemeData` the issue got fixed :)